# The custom error module does not recognize this error

Tags: web-applications, outlook, session-timeout, memory-dump, postdata

If you hit "**The custom error module does not recognize this error**" in Outlook Web Access, and you're in Firefox; then your session probably just timed out!  You just wrote a big email!!!  If you go BACK, all form fields will be BLANK!

Instead of trying to dump postdata, use wireshark on https, or anything else ridiculous: **Open a new tab or window in Firefox, and in that new tab/window go and re-login to your OWA site.  Go back to the failed to submit tab/window, and right click in the message body area -> This Frame... -> Reload this frame -> Resubmit form!  Your email will successfully send.**

If this trick doesn't suit you, then I suggest reviewing Lazarus (Firefox addon); remembering to use a text editor and save your email letter; or at the very least skimp by and "Ctrl+C" copy the message body before you submit it.  Hopefully this helps anyone looking in Google results wondering how to get their message back.

**Now, my question is: what else can you do in this same situation?**  *Precious form data is in memory, the https web application [or at least the session] you were working with is now gone, and plenty of your unsaved work hangs in the balance.*

Assuming this is on win32, *what can you do to get it back?*

e.g. Can you memory dump somehow?  Configure a proxy and print the stream? Can Firefox's session data be accessed without closing or restarting the process?  Give some ideas please?

Comment: Because Firefox is not, shall we say, 'ideally integrated with apps like Outlook or Sharepoint', I've gone back to using IE. It's not *so* bad.

Comment: OWA is simply awful in this regard. I've encountered that error a few times (Chrome on Windows 7 64 bit).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use IE Tab Plus add on or a similar to automatically render OWA using IE's engine. Works like a champ for me.